# Oracle Date Function with between operator is not giving proper result in oracle 10g?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I developed a query like

```
select accountname count(transactions)
from table1 group by accountname
where date between '27-mar-2012' and '27-jan-2013'
```

but it is giving all transactions without considering between and operator i.e it is considering all values from jan to dec. My table contain date column values like 27-mar-2012 ...

If i use

```
select accountname count(transactions) from table1
group by accountname
where date between cast('27-mar-2012' as date) and cast( '27-jan-2013' as date)
```

I am getting wrong result.

How can i fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'all values from jan to dec' - you get records before 27-Mar-2012, after 27-Jan-2013, both, or something else? Since the code you've posted isn't valid you've presumably retyped it - we're more likely to spot errors if you cut and paste code that actually demonstrates the problem, plus sample data and perhaps table structures. You shouldn't rely on implicit date conversion, but just had a horrible thought... those values are really stored in a `DATE` column aren't they, not as `VARCHAR2`? I know you said 'stored in date column', but still, the table structure would clarify.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that Oracle is running the query:

```
select accountname, count(transactions)
from table1
group by accountname
```

Because the `where` clause is not valid after the `group by`.

I would suggest:

```
select accountname, count(transactions)
from table1
where date between to_date('2012-03-27', 'yyyy-mm-dd') and to_date('2013-01-27', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
group by accountname
```

`to_date()` is safer than `convert()`.  And it is a good idea (IMHO) to use ANSI standard date formats.